# How plot a 3-order tensor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, tensor, visualize

```
a = zeros(100,100,100);
distance = [1,21,41,61,81];
for d = 1:5
    for i=distance(d): distance(d)+19
        for j=distance(d): distance(d)+19
            for k=distance(d): distance(d)+19
                a(i,j,k) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The tensor `a` with size (100,100,100) and all element dominate the diagonal.

How to visulize `a` it in `MATLAB` with zero is white color and one is black color.  I plot in MS office, this is what I want [Expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQupY.png)

For matrix case, we can visualize as follow

```
X = zeros(100,100);
distance = [1,21,41,61,81];
for d = 1:5
    for i=distance(d): distance(d)+19
        for j=distance(d): distance(d)+19
            X(i,j) = 1;
        end
    end
end


imagesc(a)
im = imagesc(1-X)
colormap(gray(256))
```

And the image is 
[2D matrix visulize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68VrW.png)

How to do a similar way for tensor?

And how to visulize tensor with noise? like noise on matrix [image: here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get pretty close to the plot produced in MS Office using `isosurface` and `isocaps`. AFAIK MATLAB doesn't have any built-in way of producing oblique projections, but if you're okay with an orthographic projection the following may work for you.

```
color = [0.2,0.2,0.2];
p1 = patch(isosurface(a), 'FaceColor', color, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
p2 = patch(isocaps(a), 'FaceColor', color, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

camlight left
camlight
lighting gouraud
isonormals(a, p1);

grid on;
view(3);
camorbit(-40,0);
```

[image]

Comment: Cool..  the surface reflect the light, can you remove it, and make it pure black color?

Comment: is it also work if we add noise on the tensor `a`? such as the figure with have some black point outside the diagonal?

Comment: You can remove the 4 lines in the middle to remove lighting.

Comment: Tensor `a` is treated as a boolean array, if you add noise do you mean randomly flipping falses to true? Then yes black patches will be created. If you mean just adding non-zero noise to the entire array you will end up with a giant black cube.

Comment: Thanks, I want add noise to each element of tensor like `a(i,j,k) + 0.5*rand(1,1)`

Comment: What do you expect the visualization to look like? If you want to show only points over a certain threshold then you should probably use `b = a > thresh` then plot `b` instead of `a`. Where `thresh` is a scalar containing the minimum value you want to show.

Comment: I update an example for martix case about noise (see the above figure). Can you code work for noise tensor?

Comment: I would like to help with the noisy visualization but I don't know what you really expect the output to look like. The 2D grayscale image doesn't extend nicely to 3D. If you can find an example of what you're looking for in 3D I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with scatter3:

```
nonzeros = find(a);
[px,py,pz] = ind2sub(size(a),nonzeros);
scatter3(px,py,pz,'k','.');
```